# LibSVM - Model is Empty

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am new to LibSVM and I would like to predict certain values based on a set of training values formed by 3 variables. This is an example of training data (testing is similar):

```
1 2 3 232  
3 4 5 23  
6 7 8 126  
9 10 11 57  
...
```

I used LibSVM in the following way:

```
 param.s=3  
 param.C=max(train_data.y)-min(train_data.x)  
 param.t=2  
 param.g=2^-13  
 param.p=2^17
 param.libsvm=['-s',param.s,'-t',param.t,'-c',param.C,'-g',param.g,'-p',param.p]  
 model=svmtrain[train_data.y,train_data.x,param.libsvm]
```

train_data.y is a vector of 1000x1, while train_data.x is a matrix 1000x3. The problem is that "model" is empty, Then I have the prediction part:

```
[y_hat,accuracy,projection]=svmpredict(test_data.y,test_data.x,model);
```

in which test_data.y is a 3998x1 vector while test_data.x is a 3998x3 matrix.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line:

```
param.libsvm=['-s',param.s,'-t',param.t,'-c',param.C,'-g',param.g,'-p',param.p]
```

You can't concatenate strings with numbers like that, and the options need spaces.
It should be

```
param.libsvm=[' -s ',num2str(param.s),' -t ',num2str(param.t),' -c ',num2str(param.C),' -g ',num2str(param.g),' -p ',num2str(param.p)]
```